# How do I sequence animations in Java?

Tags: java

How can I prevent animations from playing on top of one another?

I have a little robot that I want to move around a grid. I'm using RotateTransition and TranslateTransition to do so. I have methods for *turnLeft*, *turnRight*, and *moveForward*. The problem is that when I run *turnLeft* and then *moveForward*, the 2 animations play together (rotates while translating). Or, if I run *turnLeft* twice, they stack so that it only turns once.

What I'd like is for one motion (rotate/translate) to complete before the next begins

Thread.sleep(x) worked, but it skipped the animation visually, and I've read it's not a good solution.

This was the closest solution I could come up with:

```
public void turnLeft() {

    robotActive = true;

    RotateTransition turnLeft = new RotateTransition(Duration.millis(ANIMATION_TIME), robotPoly);
    turnLeft.setByAngle(-90);
    turnLeft.setOnFinished(e -> robotActivityFinished());
    turnLeft.play();

    direction = (direction + 3) % 4;
}
```

Using *setOnFinished* works perfectly here. The trouble is I need to have it so that every method waits until *robotActive* is false.

The robot does need to be able to run infinite sequences, so simply queuing or chaining translations in a row will not work.

Comment: Pass in an observer to each method, which can be called when the animation completes, the observers job would then be to play the next animation

Comment: You can try with a queue of animation. When you ask to turnLeft this is add to the queue. Then a kind of executor will dequeue and play one by one the animation